# what is difference between "variance explained " in Random Forest and "merror" in XGBoost

Tags: r, random-forest, xgboost

I've been wondering about a topic written at the title.

Actually, I tried both of library to predict and got a result,
but I don't know whether both scores think same or not.

Here is a sample of result..

```
XGBoost>>
train-merror:0.718701
```

As I know, `merror` is false predict score.
So, true prediction score is `1 - 0.718701 = 0.281299`.

It means this model I made can predict correct result about 28%

```
Random Forest>>
variance explained : 0.301
```

As the samples like above, is it possible to interpret the prediction score of RF is better than XGBoost result?

In fact, I hope to know whether `variance explained` and `merror` same or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Variance explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_variation) and XGBoost's `merror` are *not* the same. They relate to very different statistical concepts.

1. `merror` is the multiclass classification error rate. It is calculated as (# wrong cases) / (# all cases), see e.g. the [XGBoost R package manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf). In a binary classification problem, the numerator then corresponds to the sum of the number of false positives and false negatives, i.e. the sum of the number of Type I and II errors of the model.
2. Variance explained is exactly that: the fraction of variance in the response that is explained by the model. This is the R^2 value in a simple linear model, which is equal to the squared correlation coefficient.

---

It is perhaps useful to manually calculate and compare the classification error rate (`merror` in `xgboost`) for two multi-class classification models; here we choose the `iris` dataset and use a random forest and XGBoost classification model to predict `Species ~ .`. Following is a reproducible example.

We start by loading the necessary libraries

```
library(xgboost)
library(randomForest)
```

We now train both models on the full `iris` data and show the respective confusion matrices.

```
# Model: Random forest
model.rf <- randomForest(
    Species ~ ., data = iris)
cm.rf <- model.rf$confusion
cm.rf
#           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
#setosa         50          0         0        0.00
#versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
#virginica       0          3        47        0.06

# Model: XGBoost
model.xg <- xgboost(
    data = as.matrix(iris[, 1:4]),
    label = as.factor(iris[, 5]),
    nrounds = 10,
    eval.metric = "merror",
    num_class = 4) 
pred <- levels(iris[, 5])[as.integer(predict(model.xg, as.matrix(iris[, 1:4])))]
cm.xg <- table(pred, as.factor(iris[, 5]))
cm.xg
#
#pred         setosa versicolor virginica
#  setosa         50          0         0
#  versicolor      0         48         0
#  virginica       0          2        50
```

We can now define a convenience function to calculate the classification error as explained above.

```
merror <- function(cm)
    sum(setdiff(as.integer(cm), diag(cm))) / sum(as.integer(cm))
```

The classification errors of both models are then

```
    # Model: Random forest
    merror.rf <- merror(cm.rf[, 1:3])
    merror.rf
    #[1] 0.02

    # Model: XGBoost
    merror.xg <- merror(cm.xg)
    merror.xg
    #[1] 0.01333333
```

Notice how the value for `merror.xg` is identical to that of the final iteration in the `evaluation_log` of the XGBoost model

```
model.xg$evaluation_log
#    iter train_merror
# 1:    1     0.026667
# 2:    2     0.020000
# 3:    3     0.020000
# 4:    4     0.020000
# 5:    5     0.020000
# 6:    6     0.020000
# 7:    7     0.013333
# 8:    8     0.013333
# 9:    9     0.013333
#10:   10     0.013333
```

Comment: thank you for a comment Maurits.
is it okay to understand both evaluation criteria  are different so there have to interpret separately. 
is there a way to compare both criteria directly? or other..

best,
dean

Comment: As I explain, they relate to *different* concepts (classification error vs. variance). So I'm not sure what you mean by "to compare both criteria directly". They are *two different measures/statistics* to assess the performance of *two different models*. To compare the *same statistic*, you could calculate the classification error of your RF model and compare that with the classification error of your boosting model.